# Доступ к данным в памяти из нескольких php-скриптов

Tags: php

В БД хранятся котировки валют. Эти данные часто используются php-скриптами, причем за один запрос пользователя читается более одной записи из таблицы.

Хотелось бы целиком поместить содержимое таблицы в память в виде массива php, таким образом, чтобы разные php-cкрипты могли иметь к нему доступ.
Также этот массив должен периодически обновляться.

Это можно реализовать в PHP? Может какая технология существует?

Comment: __Кеширование__.

Comment: Если памяти на серваке более чем достаточно - можно ипользовать например [memcached](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/book.memcached.php). Или присмотреть другой механизм кэширования - по своему вкусу. Да хоть в той же БД хранить уже выбранные _текущие_ курсы и выбирать из них, а не из архива за 15 лет. Точно быстрее будет.